# Pre-load/Extend Loading Time/Add to Cache when downloading picture from Hyperlink VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code that open up a hyperlink of a picture and add it to my Excel sheet in specific cell. The code works as intended. But still some of the picture does not load properly.

When i find a "broken picture", i can go to the hyperlink, press it, and open it in my browser. When i then run the code again the picture get added to to the excel sheet as intended.

So the problem must be that the loading time to open the link is too long, and when i have opened it manually, it is then added to my Cache, and therefor loading quicker.

So my question is if there is a way to raise the allowed loading time, Pre-load it and add it to the Cache, or something i havn't though about?

It consist of 2-300 pictures, and i'll have to make it manually where most picture changes, so i can't open the "Broken Pictures" Manually every time

My Code looks like the following

```
            With OutputSheet.Cells(StartRow + SecondRow, 0 + OutTop10)   
            PicLink = DataSheet.Cells(Top10 + SecondRow + DataRow, 6)     

On Error GoTo ErrJumpDR
            Set Pic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(PicLink)              
                Pic.Top = .Top
                Pic.Left = .Left
                Pic.Height = .Height
                Pic.Width = .Width

            End With

ErrJumpDR:
        On Error GoTo -1
```

I'm using this solution that i have seen a few places already and adjusted it a bit to fit my problem.
The "On Error GoTo" also works as intended, since a few of the pictures does not exist(I know that most of the pictures that does not load exist :D.), and also to keep the code running when it dosn't load the picture. The problem was there also before i added the OnError goto

Hope that there is anybody that can help :)

Comment: My recommendation: Download all the pictures into a folder (maybe a temporary folder) first and add them from there into Excel. So you are in control of the download process and don't need rely on that `.Parent.Pictures.Insert(PicLink)` works with a URL. • So if there is an issue in the download process (eg. invalid link) you can immediatele react on it. • You will find many tutorials how to download a file with VBA properly.

Comment: Could be an option, but i would have to rewrite everything i have for it. But would be a better solution going forward, if i want to use these pictures more often.

I have made a workaround on it for now. Where i "Preload" all the picture, by a seperate code, that opens the links one by one in my browser. When running the code afterwards every single picture is loaded correctly. It ain't pretty, but it works

Comment: Well depending on how many pictures you will have in future you might become interested in speeding it up. Then I would definitly go for the folder download than downloading the picture twice.